# Xamarin forms: Load more items without button click

Tags: xamarin.forms

Dears,

I am implementing load more items to listview without a button.

My code:

```
 public partial class DashBoardPage : ContentPage
  {
ObservableCollection<string> Items;
bool isLoading;

public DashBoardPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    var listview = new ListView();

    listview.ItemsSource = Items;
    listview.ItemAppearing += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (isLoading || Items.Count == 0)
            return;

        //hit bottom!
        if (e.Item.ToString() == Items[Items.Count - 1])
        {
            LoadItems();
        }
    };
    LoadItems();
}

public async void LoadItems()
{
    isLoading = true;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("My Url");
    string tweetJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    UserTweetResponse userTweetResponse = new UserTweetResponse();
    if (tweetJson != "")
    {
        userTweetResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserTweetResponse>(tweetJson.ToString());
        foreach (var tweet in userTweetResponse.userTweetsList)
                    {
                        Items.Add(tweet.ToString());
                    }
    }
    ListView1.ItemsSource = userTweetResponse.userTweetsList;
    isLoading = false;
}
}
```

I refer the following link and confused with the for loop inside LoadItems():
https://montemagno.com/load-more-items-at-end-of-listview-in/

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
 {
  Items.Add (string.Format("Item {0}", Items.Count));
 }
```

In my case I am using itemSource property to bind the response to list view.

My model class:

```
 public class UserTweetResponse
   {
      public List<UserTweetsList> userTweetsList { get; set; }
    }
public class UserTweetsList
{
    public int tweetId { get; set; }
    public string tweetData { get; set; }
    public string createdTime { get; set; }
    public int commentCount { get; set; }
    public int likeCount { get; set; }
    public int flagCount { get; set; }
    public string mediaUrl { get; set; }
    public string tweetUser { get; set; }
    public bool userLiked { get; set; }
    public bool userFlagged { get; set; }
    public bool isMediaUrlNull { get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaUrl); } }
}
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to add your new items to your Items collection. At the moment you are replacing the ItemsSource which is wrong.

Comment: By itemSource property, I am binding the values in xaml. So if I replace that I can't show the values in UI. I don't know how to add new items to Items collection. I try like Items = userTweetResponse.userTweetsList; but getting conversion error. userTweetResponse is my model class object.

Comment: You need to add the new tweets to the existing Items collection like foreach (tweet in userTweetResponse.userTweetsList) { Items.Add(tweet); }

Comment: I would also recommend extracting your web calling code into a helper class so you are not creating a new HttpClient every time you load more tweets

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pasete this whole:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace SmartTweet
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class DashBoardPage : ContentPage
{
    int i = 1;
    bool loadMore;
    ObservableCollection<UserTweetsList> Items =new ObservableCollection<SmartTweet.UserTweetsList>();
    bool isLoading;
    UserTweetResponse userTweetResponse;
    public DashBoardPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



        ListView1.ItemAppearing += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (isLoading || Items!=null &&  Items.Count == 0)
                return;

            //hit bottom
            if (userTweetResponse.userTweetsList!=null && userTweetResponse.userTweetsList.Count>0)
            {
                UserTweetsList item = userTweetResponse.userTweetsList[userTweetResponse.userTweetsList.Count - 1];
                if ((e.Item as UserTweetsList).tweetId.ToString() == item.tweetId.ToString())
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Enter bottom");
                    loadMore = true;
                    UserTweetsList();

                }
            }


        };

    }
    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        await UserTweetsList();


        base.OnAppearing();
    }
    async void ButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadMore = true;
       // await UserTweetsList();
    }

    public async Task UserTweetsList()
    {
        isLoading = true;
        if (loadMore)
        {
            i = i + 1;
        }
        int countInInt = i * 3;
        try
        {
            string applicationId = "1";
            string siteId = "5";
            string userId = "225";
            string ownedBy = "me";
            string period = "before";
            string count = countInInt.ToString();

            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
            string date = dt.Year.ToString() + "-" + dt.Month.ToString() + "-" + dt.Day.ToString() + " " + dt.Hour.ToString() + ":" + dt.Minute.ToString() + ":" + dt.Second.ToString() + "." + dt.Millisecond.ToString();

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync("web service url");
            string tweetJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine("tweetList:>" + tweetJson);

             userTweetResponse = new UserTweetResponse();
            if (tweetJson != "")
            {
                userTweetResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserTweetResponse>(tweetJson.ToString());
                foreach (var tweet in userTweetResponse.userTweetsList)
                {
                    if (!Items.Contains(tweet))
                    {
                        Items.Add(tweet);
                    }

                    //Items.Add(tweet.ToString());
                }
            }
            ListView1.ItemsSource = userTweetResponse.userTweetsList;
            isLoading = false;
            if (userTweetResponse.userTweetsList.Count == 0)
            {
                //loadMoreButton.IsVisible = false;
                blue_holo_circle.IsVisible = false;
                blueLine.IsVisible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //loadMoreButton.IsVisible = true;
                blue_holo_circle.IsVisible = true;
                blueLine.IsVisible = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>" + ex);
        }
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: As this is the accepted answer, perhaps you can explain how it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your new tweets to your Items collection

```
public async void LoadItems()
{
    isLoading = true;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("My Url");
    string tweetJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    UserTweetResponse userTweetResponse = new UserTweetResponse();
    if (tweetJson != "")
    {
        userTweetResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserTweetResponse>(tweetJson.ToString());
        foreach (var tweet in userTweetResponse.userTweetsList)
        {
            Items.Add(tweet);
        }
    }
    isLoading = false;
}
```

because the Observable collection is the ListView item source the new items will appear in the list.

Comment: getting an error for 'in', "Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement", missing something?

Comment: I missed the var from the foreach

Comment: Also showing error for tweet in Items.Add(tweet); does not exist in the current context. Please have a look on the question, I add the model class details into it....

Comment: You'll have to debug that one yourself. My code was more a suggestion rather than a fully working solution.

Comment: Change like this: Items.Add(tweet.ToString()); But still not entering into the hit bottom else block:
     if (e.Item.ToString() == Items[Items.Count - 1])
                {
                }